# How to parse phone number as JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

**The main stuff**

I receive an MQTT packet (which appears as an ASCII array to the buffer in format [after being printed using stringify]):

```
packet = {
    "cmd": "publish",
    "retain": true,
    "qos": 1,
    "dup": false,
    "length": 36,
    "topic": "topic/subtopic",
    "payload": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [123,34,50,57,34,58,43,52,52,55,56,53,49,54,56,53,50,51,52,125]
    },
    "messageId": 3
}
```

`packet.payload` converts to `{"29":+447...}` which is the beginning of a mobile number. When passed into `JSON.parse(packet.payload)`, it throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token + in JSON at position 6`.

My question is how can I extract the value (and less importantly, the key)?

**Extra (probably unnecessary) context you can skip over**

The error makes sense since `+` isn't a valid number type and it's not encased as a string.
I attempted convert the value to a string using a reviver function and a filter, with no success, nor was I able to get the whole thing treated as a string with `JSON.stringify(packet.payload)`, `packet.payload.toString()` or `String(packet.payload)`. I can do a manual conversion from ASCII chars to string between `{`, `:` and `}` but I'm looking for a more robust, generalised solution that doesn't manipulate the ASCII.

Parsing works as expected on a different packet `{"6000":100}` to give an expected key value pair return.

Using `.entries()` returned some weird behaviour - (on the other packet) it returned `6000,100` which was of array type, but unusable as an array or number (as far as I could figure out). This might hint as to what's going on?

I was also wondering whether it was possible to extend the behaviour of `.parse()` to accept a number in the form `+44...` or to take that value and return it as `"+44..."`.

**Edit for extra clarity:**

The first thing I wanted to do was limit the output datatypes from the upstream device (a PLC) to primitives (like int) only, however this isn't possible or even enforceable, so my broker needs to be able to handle whatever is thrown at it even if it's invalid type.

With regards to why the packet comes in a JSON format? I honestly don't know - but I'd think it's either how MQTT natively works, or the Aedes broker service I'm running on Node.
The broker has an event `publish` which will emit the client and the packet whenever a publisher publishes a packet. This is how I am receiving the packet on the server end of things.

Comment: I would recommend to at least post the whole package instead of doing . . ., and also include an actual phone #. I would have played a bit with this, but not having an actual package and an actual # is hard to know what the result should be.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of how MQTT works, but it is surprising that you're able to configure it in such a way that noncompliant JSON like this is generated and sent along to your script. As you've discovered, the built-in JSON parser (and any other spec-compliant one, for that matter) will complain about this data. Is there a chance the upstream datasource can be reconfigured such that it sends valid JSON? That would probably the cleanest, most "*robust, generalised solution that doesn't manipulate the ASCII*" and prevent issues like this in the future.

Comment: @HanletEscaño I'll try and copy over a fuller packet for you. Obviously, I'll be editing the number since it isn't my own.

Comment: @esqew I tried configuring the upstream device today, but it's proving impossible to do. I *knew* I'd forgotten to mention something. It's a PLC and therefore very uncofigurable.

Comment: @HanletEscaño I hope that's enough clarity for you. This is the direct output I get from stringifying the packet I receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will take the array and convert it back to a string via a buffer.

```
var buffer = Buffer.from(packet.payload.array)
var string = buffer.toString('utf8')
```

In that case that `packet.payload` is already a buffer then the following should work:

```
var buffer = Bufffer.from(packet.payload)
```

EDIT:

```
var regex = /{ \"\d+\": (\+\d+) }/
var matches = packet.payload.toString('utf8').match(regex)
var phoneNumber = matches[1]
```

Comment: Using `packet.payload` returns `{"29":+447...}`. I can't actually access the array intuitively. I have to intercept it and convert it to string first, which feels like something that'll throw hiccups later down the line. 
`packet.payload.data` and `packet.payload["29"]` are both undefined type.

I'll post output once I can get the array out and then do the conversion.

Comment: Using test data `{"1":+44}`  and the following code:
`var arr = Buffer.from(packet.payload)` pulls out the packet data.
Applying your code, then the parser, still returns the unexpected token error.

Using `JSON.stringify(packet.payload.toString())` returned `"{\"1\":+44}"` to console. That seems like a janky way to do it though so I'm not confident.

Comment: I do believe it is already a buffer (noting the `"type": "Buffer"` in the packet). Using `Buffer.from(packet.payload)`  returned `{"1":+44}` to console, which again couldn't be parsed as JSON.

Comment: ahh, sorry, just twigged. Because it's not valid JSON (the leading `+` is the problem. To be valid JSON it needs to be presented as a string (wrapped in quotes). You are going to need to parse the string in the payload by hand (regex)

Comment: Ah okay, that'll do it. I wanted to avoid any hardcoding if possible, but it's looking like the only way since I can't get a valid datatype from the upstream device. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: The regex match returns as null. I'm not entirely sure why, but I guess it'll just take a bit of fiddling around to get it to work...

Comment: Take the spaces out of the regex